# How to map unsigned data types correctly with NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I wonder how I could actually map an UInt16 value to a corresponding database type without a big fuzz.

We are working with Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5, NHibernate and FluentNHibernate for configuration.

**Straight forward approach - will result in an error**

```
public class Identificator
{
    public Identificator( ushort componentType, ushort componentID ) { ... }

    public virtual ushort ComponentType { get; protected set; }
    public virtual ushort ComponentID { get; protected set; }

    ...
}

public class IdentificatorMapping : ClassMap<Identificator>
{
    public IdentificatorMapping()
    {
        this.Map( x => x.ComponentType );
        this.Map( x => x.ComponentID );

        ...
    }
}
```

When actually creating a new object on the database ...

```
// Create Object
Identificator persistableObjectOK = new Identificator( 0x0001, 0x0001 );

// Persist it
ISession session = GetSession();
session.Save( persistableObjectOK );
```

... I'll get that error, which is OK, as SQL Server CE does not know unsigned types

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>   System.ArgumentException: Dialect does not support DbType.UInt16

**Using CustomSqlType - works partly**

So, I went and forced NHibernate to take an integer which is 4 bytes long on the database and so should cover the data range of an UInt16

```
public class IdentificatorMapping : ClassMap<Identificator>
{
    public IdentificatorMapping()
    {
        this.Map( x => x.ComponentType ).CustomSqlType( "INTEGER" );
        this.Map( x => x.ComponentID ).CustomSqlType( "INTEGER" );

        ...
    }
}
```

The result is working ... as long as I stay below 32767!
Above that value, the whole thing blows up.

The strange thing is that, up in the application it is unsigned 2 bytes. Down in the database it is signed 4 bytes.

Both should be sufficient to store up to 65536

However, NHibernate is not yet convinced. At some place down to the database it tries to convert UInt16 into Int16.

```
System.Convert.ToInt16(UInt16 value)
System.UInt16.System.IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
System.Data.SqlServerCe.Accessor.set_Value(Object value)
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.FillParameterDataBindings(Boolean verifyValue)
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()
NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.SaveOrUpdate(String entityName, Object obj)
NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction.SaveUpdateCascadingAction.Cascade(IEventSource session, Object child, String entityName, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled)
NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeToOne(Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled)
NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeAssociation(Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled)
NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeProperty(Object child, IType type, CascadeStyle style, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled)
NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.CascadeBeforeSave(IEventSource source, IEntityPersister persister, Object entity, Object anything)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
```

Concrete question: how could I say NHibernate not to do this conversion, but convert from UIn16 to Int32 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In analogy to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309072/nhibernate-how-to-store-uint32-in-database) I created a user type that stores UInt16 in Int16.
The trade-in is that the representation within the database may look wrong (i.e. shows a negative value) if we exceed 32K.

```
using System;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.SqlTypes;
using NHibernate.UserTypes;

public class UInt16UserType : IUserType
{
    public Object NullSafeGet( System.Data.IDataReader rs, String[] names, Object owner )
    {
        Int16? i = (Int16?) NHibernateUtil.Int16.NullSafeGet( rs, names[0] );
        return (UInt16?) i;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet( System.Data.IDbCommand cmd, Object value, int index )
    {
        UInt16? u = (UInt16?) value;
        Int16? i = (Int16?) u;
        NHibernateUtil.Int16.NullSafeSet( cmd, i, index );
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Nullable<UInt16>);
        }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlType[] {SqlTypeFactory.Int16};
        }
    }

    public Object Assemble( Object cached, Object owner )
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object DeepCopy( Object value )
    {
        return value;
    }

    public Object Disassemble( Object value )
    {
        return value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( Object x )
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Object Replace( Object original, Object target, Object owner )
    {
        return original;
    }

    public new bool Equals( Object x, Object y )
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals( x, y ))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(x is UInt16 && y is UInt16))
        {
            return false;
        }

        UInt16 a = (UInt16) x;
        UInt16 b = (UInt16) y;

        bool result = a == b;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server (including CE) doesn't support unsigned types, so there is no valid type to convert to. The exception is byte / tinyint.

You could probably write a custom IUserType implementation to do the conversion for ushort and int but it would be much simpler to use int in your code.

See also: [Does using small datatypes (for example short instead of int) reduce memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198240/does-using-small-datatypes-for-example-short-instead-of-int-reduce-memory-usag)

Comment: Using int is not quite an option. It would give me the "room" to store greater values, but would lead to misunderstandings when other people would use these classes. I would have to document that "there is an int, but please do only use 2 byte values"... So, I think I'll go for the user type, then.

Comment: For background information: The data type is defined by an protocol, as "2 bytes unsigned"

Comment: If half of `UInt16.MaxValue` which is what you get with `Int16` is enough then you should go with @Seven 's solution, in other case you should switch to a DB that supports unsigned numerical.